# Axios serving png image is giving broken image

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, axios, ramda.js

I am using express as middle-ware api.A person hits my middle-ware , it hits some third party api and returns back the result. Its working fine for all other end points expect an get end point that creates an png and serves it.
so under method returns response

```
   _execute = R.curry((reqFunction, req, res) => {
        reqFunction(req, res).
        then(r => {
          res.status(r.status).header(r.headers).send(r.data)
        }).
        catch(err => {
          res.status(err.response.status).header(err.headers).send(err.response.data)
        })
      });
```

and `reqFunction` is method like

```
  modelDiagram = (req, res) => {
    const headers = req.headers;
    const modelName = req.params['modelName'];
    const endPoint = this.modelDiagramEndPoint + '/' + modelName;
    return this.httpRequests.get(endPoint, headers);
  }
```

and `httpRequests.get` method is

```
  get = (endPoint, headers) => {
    let options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: endPoint
    }
    options = this.addHeaders(headers, options);
    return this._send(options);
  }
```

and this._send is like

```
  _send = (options) => {
    return axios(options);
  };
```

the response if I directly hit from browser is like
```
�PNG

IHDRn��7Q�
IDATx���oHk����D�ȥ|!H�DD�^)"k"n�̤$H�V뒻�Vж"�+��n-"�[��XL��լ�[Z�^����lnK&K���=�9�9z�sʋs�~���g�g��g����gf��l��z��QIcc�dEE�<��?�\YY�վ}�R7!{�����'O�T�C�x�B�fff��۷UYYٿ8��^�a�  ������?��92O��L2w�����{���s�NXZ��k۝N�r�\�<.�N������/_���尵�����ϫ���E�['���"�x˞|f   ���~��N��K�d�����u���3j��u5�����%p6���Sj���ꛎ3>�<)�M�M�y4���v��ܳ{�
N�gSpCw~��p�[Opr��Φ�F��M@pR8��[�z������ä'O�g����-+�I7�v�����oW��<)�
�ɓ�|�p��2;<=�)�fF;Փ��4 4ò�����8Qf����V�,X�n��},4À���H�8�n}}�������8"���À7p�/]��j����h�0g�@Bfપ�Too/������z��mD�
8���Ḹ8�w�^������v�ڵ��v�ܩ��������ݭˬgX�ۺu����
x@###:��N(�Ο?��o߮6o޼�'YSS�n߉'|����Tcccx����P���*::Z����h1�v�U~~����Q)))����9�V;�[�n�tAA����U����l+P$O�[��̙3�3׹Z[���|)�ϯ��WIII*>>^
|���7o�q�~��RzYT��q��@�]7p2���ZZZ�Ç}v^TT��Feee<��0�;v�P�����o�U[[�����`e��   ���Q������m]]��,//ϻ~EE��3"��ի���<h���[���Έ����;��.Y^��SYY��`�*l�'X�ն���j����4##C/���{��@u�.P{�
�Ѹ`;7��`��9�a58����j[���u����3*�Ȝ'��Zu~8��������{���ӧO��\�IWWW�lc̃����6Z�sIo۶Mϛ�p��ޮӒ'�+��3P[�yH�|e����e���аf�����+鱱1UZZj���N����T}�577���r�`��F�A����1b�b����R��0�O�拓@e���-�C%&&�mUTTԚO��$e�H1��ӿ���A}A#?��������H�����#�&7bo�%z�̐3/77W�>��#/8�a�a�p�ÀÀ�88:�Hyz�x��[�].�L$|w <55����tvv����z=77���۸HhN��;�_�yV��!�@o�l��ߟ���Y!�!�ppp�C�C����888�!�!�!�pppp�C�C������8zppp��)�>w�����k��[V��N�S�\�W�X'�zzz/��X���ˇ�-��W"
h���l�-�|w�v��������hy06���|�N1Կ�jDM/�����'�����/՝��5��w�[:���Hr�zc  �����η�37��C��U����8�a�pNn�C�ƍ�M�ɣ�P����&��a�<�����|�ppp��0�8�a�a�.���xb;u���8���k׮��?�\EEE�t��I���*))I��ǫ��]6;;����Ull����Q��`�3��|��ƍ�zU\�.����y���z���W���+�����W�Ѽ�v���RGJJ�ONN���推���!鼼<]��7ܪ��M[Ғglk�9uꔷ��������kjjt^UU�^>wr�����}&$$����H�GFF��YYY�.77W�t���d�aɼl�^ZZ�6"�XwϞ=:��@qYY�Η��O�����T�,���cLKKS���A�`�}���8pi���^xN�Gcݒ�������N���ѣ�u233u~SS�>y����d�?11���dx��9���V-,,�5栵:�#�d{{�NK���1J}:-s��˗��HZ�e~mnn^1?ÜX���9$=66�JKK}�d��tuuu䂓�]�P����VK�$J�l'��y����X�����6�?::��dH4G���P�������B��&s�� Nr���O�\���
8�0�0�8�a�a�p��8l'p��V^��t��5�w�ᩩ�/-w���sOWW�빹��t��E�@s:��Y�҇ȳ�n��|�fC,��,$h!�B!����?Ǔ�8���IEND�B`�
```

but image is broken. I have tried many things like `req.end` and explicitly setting headers but I am not able to solve it.Please guide me

Comment: Have you tried configuring the content type in your Axios options? By default, the expected content type is JSON. I'm guessing for a binary file you'll have to use blob or stream

Comment: @PatrickHund I tried that

Comment: I suggest turning image to Base64 strings and then sending them. I have a very good experience using them. every browser can render that without any problem.

Comment: Okay I will try that @HosseinAgha

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry for late answer but maybe someone find this approach more reliable:

```
axios.get('/path/to/image.png', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
.then(response => {
      let blob = new Blob(
        [response.data], 
        { type: response.headers['content-type'] }
      )
      let image = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      return image
    })
```

How I understand this:

1. When you specifies in options `{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' }` axios will set `response.data` to `ArrayBuffer`
2. Next you create file-like object - Blob
3. You get url to blob-file via `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` that you can use in `src` attribute of `img` tag

As described in this [article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2966-rendering-image-previews-using-object-urls-vs-base64-data-uris-in-angularjs.htm) approach above should be faster.

Here is jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fotonmoton/j41tgs32/9/)

UPD:

Just find out that you can specify in options `responseType: 'blob'` so you don't need to create `Blob` object yourself:

```
axios.get('https://picsum.photos/300/300', {responseType: 'blob'})
.then(response => {
  let imageNode = document.getElementById('image');
  let imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
  imageNode.src = imgUrl
})
```

Jsfiddle [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fotonmoton/3woztqsg/1/)

Here axios [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/448) about missing documentation for binary data manipulation. In this [comment](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/448#issuecomment-333791136) you can find the same approach that I suggest. Also you can use `FileReader` API, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743665/3175823) stackoverflow comment you can find pros and cons for both approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You just try this

```
return axios.get(<URL WHICH RETURNS IMAGE IN STRING ex:'http://host/image.png'>, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
  .then((response) => {
    let image = btoa(
      new Uint8Array(response.data)
        .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
    );
    return `data:${response.headers['content-type'].toLowerCase()};base64,${image}`;
  });
```