# How to convert image data response to Image base64?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

this is my api

https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/icon?url=facebook.com&size=80..120..200

when I am testing this in postman I am getting Image..But how I can do with `axios`.
I am getting very long string(like �PNG...) right now with Axios

So how I can use that response to show the image..

```
   axios.get(RequestURL, { withCredentials: false })
                .then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    console.log(response)
                    var b64Response = btoa(response.data) 
                    setImageServer('data:image/png;base64,' + b64Response) // not showing image
                })
```

Also getting error when try to run `btoa`

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be
> encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

HTML

```
 <img src={ImageServer}/>
```

Comment: That is not base64 image

Comment: `https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yN/r/EWLVhDVJTum.png` this is png image

Comment: yes it's not but I want to convert it base64 so I can show it on image src

Comment: no need convert base64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
axios.get('RequestURL', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
.then(response => {
      let blob = new Blob(
        [response.data], 
        { type: response.headers['content-type'] }
      )
      let image = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      return image
    })
```

```
axios.get('RequestURL', {responseType: 'blob'})
.then(response => {
  let imageNode = document.getElementById('image');
  let imgUrl = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
  imageNode.src = imgUrl
})
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785229/axios-serving-png-image-is-giving-broken-image

Comment: So why not close this question as duplicate instead of copy/pasting the code from another answer? Am I missing something?

Comment: URL.createObjectURL is not a function

Comment: please use `window.URL.createObjectURL`

Comment: Can I save this image locally ?? as base64

Comment: to the local storage

Comment: I think, that is impossible