# How to convert Vec<u8> png response from actix-web/rust into Buffer in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, rust, type-conversion, buffer

I have two APIs that talk to each other, one is written in rust (actix-web) and the other in node. My nodejs application is requesting a PNG from the actix API. The actix API response is a Vec representation of a PNG image. I have not been able to use the response from actix with much success because I am having trouble converting the response data/body into a usable format.

the code on the actix side looks something like this:

```
pub async fn handle_image<C: repository::C, M: repository::M>(
    c_repository: web::Data<C>,
    m_repository: web::Data<M>,
    input: web::Json<model::InputModel>,
) -> HttpResponse {
    images::generate_image(
        c_repository.get_ref(),
        m_repository.get_ref(),
        &input.into(),
    )
    .await
    .map(|result| match result {
        Result::Success(image) => {
            HttpResponse::Ok()
                .insert_header(ContentType::png())
                .body(image)
        },
        _ => HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish(),
    })
    .unwrap_or_else(|_| HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish())
}
```

The image is a `Vec<u8>` type and all of this code works as expected (I have confirmed the images are generated correctly from the rust side).

My code on the javascript (typescript) side currently looks something like this:

```
export const getImage = async (imageDetails: ImageDetails) => {
    const fromHexString = (hexString: string) => {
      const b = (hexString.match(/.{1,2}/g) || []).map((byte) => parseInt(byte, 16));
      return Uint8Array.from(b);
    };

    const { data } = await imageService.geImage(imageDetails);
    console.log('from', fromHexString(data as string));
    console.log('uiint8array', Uint8Array.from(data as number[]));
    console.log('hex', Buffer.from(data as string, 'hex'));
    console.log('buffer', Buffer.from(data));
  }
};
```

I've also tried using a blob. However, I have not been able to find anything that works. None of the resulting data is correctly converted and usable.

The data returned is rather large, but here is a snippet of what I see when I `console.log()` the data (on the nodejs side)

> '�PNG\r\n' +
> '\x1A\n' +
> '\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01�\x00\x00\x01�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00��%6\x00\x00\x1BVIDATx���۪$I�������3\x1E���1�Z\x1EY]\x05;�\x0F~a\x07)2������|\x03{�/a\x0F�%�!��=䗰��\x12��_�\x1E�K�C~\t{�/a\x0F�%�!��=䗰��\x12��_�\x1E�K�C~\t{�/a\x0F�%�!��=䗰��\x12��_1E�K�C~\t{�/a\x0F�%�!��=䗰��\x12��_�\x1E�K\x18\x0F�?�}´w"�k\x1F�n�%���O�[�~���\x1E2Ƚ��S�֧�b���\fr�=�Ը�鷘o�!��k\x0F?5n}�-�\x1B{�
> ���O�[�~���\x1E2Ƚ��S�֧�b���\fr�=�Ը�鷘o�!��k\x0F?5n}�-�\x1Bׇ�zh�O�d�<}dN7����=z⶿�<�AN7����=z⶿�<�AN7����=z⶿�<�AN7����=z⶿�<�A���=z⶿�<�AN7����=z⶿�<�AN7����=z⶿�<�AN7����=z����t���n��&�I���\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!��\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!��\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!��\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!��\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!��\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!��\x1E��Ǉ��:ɜn�!

I also printed what was being sent by actix (the "image" in the actix code example) prior to sending the response. Again I won't post the whole thing, however here is a snippet:

```
 [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 1, 200, 0, 0, 1, 200, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 239, 202, 37, 54, 0, 0, 27, 86, 73, 68, 65, 84, 120, 156, 237, 209, 219, 170, 36, 73, 172, 164, 225, 217, 239, 255, 208, 51, 30, 204, 250, 160, 49, 202, 90, 30, 89, 93, 5, 59, 209, 15, 126, 97, 7, 41, 50, 209, 255,
```

The reason I post that is to say that I have compared all my attempts to parse the response from actix and they do not match what was sent. I am hoping someone might have some insight on how to make this work, I've been struggling with it so far.

Please let me know if there's any more information needed. Thanks in advance!

frameworks & environments

node: 20.9.0

nextjs: 14.0.1

rust: 1.73.0

actix-web: 4.2.1

An example of what I am having trouble with is converting the image in the response to a base64 string. When I try to run `Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')` I get a huge base64 string, here is a snippet (not the whole thing, it is too long) output:

> 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...

(Note: When I am attempting to display this data I do add the `data:image/png;base64,` prefix, this is just the output from the buffer itself)

The buffer itself looks like this:

> <Buffer ef bf bd 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 01
> ef bf bd 00 00 01 ef bf bd 08 00 00 00 00 ef bf bd ef bf bd 25 36 00
> 00 1b 56 49 44 41 ... 13398 more bytes>

This is not valid image data and does not display in the browser as expected.

Comment: What "usable format" do you need? You clearly have the PNG encoding of the image in node. If you need the actual pixels, you need a decoding library.

Comment: Agree with Colonel Thirty Two, what were you expecting differently?

Comment: The data is the same on the rust and js side. Rust is printing decimal numbers, and js is printing escaped hexadecimal numbers. They are the exact same content: a compressed image file in PNG format. If you're serving this as a PNG, you're good to go. If you need to manipulate the pixels, see @ColonelThirtyTwo's comment about deciding a PNG to a bitmap. A `Vec<u8>` is just "some bytes", not necessarily "some pixels".

Comment: @JaredSmith Thank you for your response! By usable I mean able to be manipulated and/or converted to another data type, like a base64 string for example.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thanks Colonel! I think this is where my issue lies, hopefully converting the PNG to a bitmap will do the trick.

Comment: @MarcusRuddick is `Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')` not working? Because it should...

Comment: @JaredSmith no, it is not working. I will update my question with further outputs to show what I am seeing

Comment: @MarcusRuddick, do you want the base64 of your compressed PNG, or the base64 of the decompressed bitmap? They are certainly not the same, and you're not being clear about your usages enough to determine the best course of action for you. If you're sharing this base64 over network, you almost certainly want to transmit the compressed PNG and not the raw bitmap. The PNG will almost always be smaller, and represent the exact same pixels to a client that is capable of decoding PNG (lossless compression). There are cases where you'd pass a raw bitmap to a function, but usually not base64.

Comment: Base64 for reference takes 2 bytes of potentially non ASCII and turns it into 3 bytes of ASCII. For images this will almost always bloat your size, especially when you're passing raw bitmaps around, which are exponentially larger than their compressed counterparts. For example, one compressed byte becomes N decompressed bytes, which then is base64 encoded into (N/2)*3 bytes, for a total of WIDTH*HEIGHT*((N/2)*3) bytes. That's a lot of overhead for a base64 bitmap.

Comment: @MeetTitan thanks for your response! Base 64 conversion was just an example/way to test. But, I figured out how to get the output I was looking for. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue based on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785229/axios-serving-png-image-is-giving-broken-image). It seems the problem was that axios needed to be configured to have a response type of `arrayBuffer` in order for the data to be returned in the form I was expecting. My solution involved adding `arrayBuffer` as the response type, like this:

```
axios.get('/image.png', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
```

Now I am able to use/manipulate the image data.

I didn't realize axios required that I specify the response type as `arraybuffer`. Apologies for the lack of information on the axios configuration and use.