# Is it possible to display an image that has been selected by an input element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wish to display an input element's selected image. Can this be performed on a local file, accessing the image client side, or would I need to upload the image to a server?

Here's my attempt in React. I can access the correct file name from the input element using `inputElem.files[0].name`. As soon as I am trying to set an image element to it, the broken image icon is displayed, and no error is surfaced.

```js
const App = () => {
  // state to keep track of img elements src. The default works fine.
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState('/images/test.jpg')

  function handleImgUpload() {
    const url = '/images/' + e.target.files[0].name
    setImgSrc(url)
    console.log(url) // /images/26e3e793-98f5-4720-9f82-8963276d5e27.JPG
  }

  function handleImgLoadSuccess() {
    console.log('image loaded!')
  }

  function handleImgLoadError() {
    console.log('image not loaded')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="img">Select an image:</label>
        <input
          type="file"
          id="img"
          name="img"
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
          onChange={(e) => handleImgUpload(e)}
        />
      </div>

      <img
        src={imgSrc}
        alt="Your upload"
        onLoad={handleImgLoadSuccess}
        onError={handleImgLoadError}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the console, however, the url seems to be correct.

```html
<img src="/images/26e3e793-98f5-4720-9f82-8963276d5e27.JPG" height="100" width="200" alt="Input" class="jsx-855240488">
```

Comment: Does that image exist on the server yet when you try to display it?

Comment: @mplungjan No, I'm purely training to access and display it client side.

Comment: `const url = '/images/' + e.target.files[0].name` does not exist client side

Comment: Sounds like you need to [look for preview image](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+preview+image+upload+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick by creating a correct blob url.

```js
const inputImg = e.target.files[0]
const url = URL.createObjectURL(inputImg)
// blob:http://localhost:3000/test-img.jpg
```

The resulting file stays in memory and needs to be removed in order to create memory leaks.

```js
URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

This also seems to be accomplishable with FileReader, though there are [differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743665/10653440).

Answer (score 0):

Hey – I see what you're trying to do, but it doesn't look like this will work. You need to create a new file reader.

```
const showTempImage = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const img = document.createElement("img");

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
        img.src = e.target.result;
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

   // Append the img tag to the dom somewhere
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damilare, this seems to work. I've opted for the slightly faster `createObjectURL`.

Comment: Nicey! All the best